# Functions with sequelize transactions and not transactions

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm developing an app using sequelize and I just started to use transaction() because I want my queries to be able to rollback on errors. So I had my regular functions

```
const customer = await Customer.findOne({ where: { email: { [Op.eq]: body.email } } });
```

and now I also have

```
const newCustomer = await Customer.create(body, { transaction: t });
```

Everything is working fine for the moment, but I can help thinking if it's a good idea in terms of performance to use both on the same operation. (looking for an already created customer and in case it doesn't exist, create a new one based on email address) I think they both are using different transactions but I'm not sure how that can affect for example my pool max number.

PD: I'm facing some issues where it seems that a query blocks or something my node and I have to restart the server to make everything work again.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forget to indicate a transaction in one or more queries than it can lead to deadlocks because you will have two transactions changing/reading the same or linked records.
You should indicate a transaction even in read operations like `findOne`:

```
const customer = await Customer.findOne({ where: { email: { [Op.eq]: body.email } }, transaction: t });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Anatoly, so to conclude, if I use transaction in a function I should use it in every "sequelize call" of that function and if i decide no to use it in a function, for example a get function where I perform a single "sequelize" operation it's also ok, right?

Comment: That's right. You can make exceptions from this rule if you retrieve some data not related with other data being changed. But that way it's easy to forget to indicate a transaction somewhere where it's required.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help